Android, Unity, Gradle: how to solve this exception /+ is exist way to automate slove problems kind of this. (Build failure Grade build failed.)
There are constant problems with gradle buildings, constant pain:
The most primary and simplest thing, probably, is to solve the problem of this building.
But! Is there any utility for gradle, like anaconda for tesnerflow/karas and the like, that installs the necessary dependencies itself, changes gradle files, etc?
Well, or at least what are the names of any companies that are engaged in builds for android? (On the other hand, this option is not for me. A: I am wildly afraid to burn the signature keys, so much so that even the logs below are thrown off. B: I don't have any money at all)

Logs:
1.
    > Configure project :unityLibrary
    Variant 'debug', will keep symbols in binaries for:
      'libunity.so'
      'libil2cpp.so'
      'libmain.so'
    Variant 'release', symbols will be stripped from binaries.
    
    > Configure project :launcher
    Variant 'debug', will keep symbols in binaries for:
      'libunity.so'
      'libil2cpp.so'
      'libmain.so'
    Variant 'release', symbols will be stripped from binaries.
    
    > Configure project :unityLibrary:GooglePlayGamesManifest.androidlib
    WARNING: minSdkVersion (24) is greater than targetSdkVersion (16) for variant "debug". Please change the values such that minSdkVersion is less than or equal to targetSdkVersion.
    WARNING: minSdkVersion (24) is greater than targetSdkVersion (16) for variant "release". Please change the values such that minSdkVersion is less than or equal to targetSdkVersion.
    
    > Task :launcher:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
    > Task :unityLibrary:YandexMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
    > Task :unityLibrary:GooglePlayGamesManifest.androidlib:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
    > Task :unityLibrary:mobilenotifications.androidlib:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
    > Task :unityLibrary:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
    > Task :unityLibrary:YandexMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
    > Task :unityLibrary:GooglePlayGamesManifest.androidlib:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
    > Task :unityLibrary:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
    > Task :launcher:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
    > Task :unityLibrary:mobilenotifications.androidlib:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
    > Task :unityLibrary:YandexMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
    > Task :launcher:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
    > Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
    > Task :unityLibrary:GooglePlayGamesManifest.androidlib:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
    > Task :unityLibrary:mobilenotifications.androidlib:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
    > Task :launcher:generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
    > Task :unityLibrary:YandexMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
    > Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
    > Task :unityLibrary:GooglePlayGamesManifest.androidlib:generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
    > Task :unityLibrary:mobilenotifications.androidlib:generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
    > Task :launcher:createReleaseCompatibleScreenManifests UP-TO-DATE
    > Task :launcher:extractDeepLinksRelease UP-TO-DATE
    > Task :unityLibrary:GooglePlayGamesManifest.androidlib:packageReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
    > Task :unityLibrary:packageReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
    > Task :unityLibrary:YandexMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:packageReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
    > Task :unityLibrary:mobilenotifications.androidlib:packageReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
    > Task :unityLibrary:extractDeepLinksRelease UP-TO-DATE
    > Task :unityLibrary:GooglePlayGamesManifest.androidlib:extractDeepLinksRelease UP-TO-DATE
    > Task :launcher:packageReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
    > Task :unityLibrary:YandexMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:extractDeepLinksRelease UP-TO-DATE
    > Task :unityLibrary:mobilenotifications.androidlib:extractDeepLinksRelease UP-TO-DATE
    > Task :unityLibrary:GooglePlayGamesManifest.androidlib:processReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
    > Task :unityLibrary:YandexMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:processReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
    > Task :unityLibrary:processReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
    > Task :unityLibrary:mobilenotifications.androidlib:processReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
    > Task :unityLibrary:mobilenotifications.androidlib:writeReleaseAarMetadata UP-TO-DATE
    > Task :unityLibrary:YandexMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:writeReleaseAarMetadata UP-TO-DATE
    > Task :unityLibrary:writeReleaseAarMetadata UP-TO-DATE
    > Task :unityLibrary:GooglePlayGamesManifest.androidlib:writeReleaseAarMetadata UP-TO-DATE
    > Task :unityLibrary:YandexMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:compileReleaseLibraryResources UP-TO-DATE
    > Task :unityLibrary:mobilenotifications.androidlib:compileReleaseLibraryResources UP-TO-DATE
    > Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseLibraryResources UP-TO-DATE
    > Task :unityLibrary:GooglePlayGamesManifest.androidlib:compileReleaseLibraryResources UP-TO-DATE
    > Task :unityLibrary:GooglePlayGamesManifest.androidlib:parseReleaseLocalResources UP-TO-DATE
    > Task :unityLibrary:parseReleaseLocalResources UP-TO-DATE
    > Task :unityLibrary:YandexMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:parseReleaseLocalResources UP-TO-DATE
    > Task :unityLibrary:mobilenotifications.androidlib:parseReleaseLocalResources UP-TO-DATE
    > Task :unityLibrary:GooglePlayGamesManifest.androidlib:generateReleaseRFile UP-TO-DATE
    > Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseRFile UP-TO-DATE
    > Task :launcher:mapReleaseSourceSetPaths UP-TO-DATE
    > Task :unityLibrary:YandexMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:generateReleaseRFile UP-TO-DATE
    > Task :unityLibrary:mobilenotifications.androidlib:generateReleaseRFile UP-TO-DATE
    > Task :unityLibrary:GooglePlayGamesManifest.androidlib:javaPreCompileRelease UP-TO-DATE
    > Task :unityLibrary:javaPreCompileRelease UP-TO-DATE
    > Task :unityLibrary:GooglePlayGamesManifest.androidlib:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac NO-SOURCE
    > Task :unityLibrary:mobilenotifications.androidlib:javaPreCompileRelease UP-TO-DATE
    > Task :launcher:mergeReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
    > Task :unityLibrary:YandexMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:javaPreCompileRelease UP-TO-DATE
    > Task :unityLibrary:GooglePlayGamesManifest.androidlib:bundleLibCompileToJarRelease UP-TO-DATE
    > Task :unityLibrary:mergeReleaseShaders UP-TO-DATE
    > Task :unityLibrary:YandexMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac NO-SOURCE
    > Task :unityLibrary:GooglePlayGamesManifest.androidlib:bundleLibRuntimeToDirRelease UP-TO-DATE
    > Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseShaders NO-SOURCE
    > Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
    > Task :unityLibrary:YandexMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:bundleLibCompileToJarRelease UP-TO-DATE
    > Task :unityLibrary:GooglePlayGamesManifest.androidlib:mergeReleaseShaders UP-TO-DATE
    > Task :unityLibrary:GooglePlayGamesManifest.androidlib:compileReleaseShaders NO-SOURCE
    > Task :unityLibrary:YandexMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:bundleLibRuntimeToDirRelease UP-TO-DATE
    > Task :unityLibrary:GooglePlayGamesManifest.androidlib:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
    > Task :unityLibrary:packageReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
    > Task :unityLibrary:YandexMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:mergeReleaseShaders UP-TO-DATE
    > Task :unityLibrary:GooglePlayGamesManifest.androidlib:packageReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
    > Task :unityLibrary:YandexMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:compileReleaseShaders NO-SOURCE
    > Task :unityLibrary:GooglePlayGamesManifest.androidlib:bundleLibRuntimeToJarRelease UP-TO-DATE
    > Task :unityLibrary:YandexMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
    > Task :unityLibrary:YandexMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:packageReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
    > Task :unityLibrary:processReleaseJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
    > Task :unityLibrary:GooglePlayGamesManifest.androidlib:processReleaseJavaRes NO-SOURCE
    > Task :unityLibrary:YandexMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:bundleLibRuntimeToJarRelease UP-TO-DATE
    > Task :launcher:processReleaseMainManifest UP-TO-DATE
    > Task :unityLibrary:GooglePlayGamesManifest.androidlib:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
    > Task :unityLibrary:GooglePlayGamesManifest.androidlib:mergeReleaseNativeLibs NO-SOURCE
    > Task :launcher:processReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
    > Task :unityLibrary:YandexMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:processReleaseJavaRes NO-SOURCE
    > Task :unityLibrary:mobilenotifications.androidlib:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
    > Task :launcher:processApplicationManifestReleaseForBundle UP-TO-DATE
    > Task :unityLibrary:GooglePlayGamesManifest.androidlib:copyReleaseJniLibsProjectOnly UP-TO-DATE
    > Task :unityLibrary:mobilenotifications.androidlib:bundleLibCompileToJarRelease UP-TO-DATE
    > Task :unityLibrary:GooglePlayGamesManifest.androidlib:prepareReleaseArtProfile UP-TO-DATE
    > Task :unityLibrary:YandexMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
    > Task :unityLibrary:mobilenotifications.androidlib:bundleLibRuntimeToDirRelease UP-TO-DATE
    > Task :unityLibrary:YandexMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:mergeReleaseNativeLibs NO-SOURCE
    > Task :unityLibrary:YandexMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:copyReleaseJniLibsProjectOnly UP-TO-DATE
    > Task :unityLibrary:mobilenotifications.androidlib:mergeReleaseShaders UP-TO-DATE
    > Task :unityLibrary:mobilenotifications.androidlib:compileReleaseShaders NO-SOURCE
    > Task :unityLibrary:YandexMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:prepareReleaseArtProfile UP-TO-DATE
    > Task :unityLibrary:mobilenotifications.androidlib:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
    > Task :launcher:checkReleaseAarMetadata UP-TO-DATE
    > Task :unityLibrary:mobilenotifications.androidlib:packageReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
    > Task :unityLibrary:mobilenotifications.androidlib:bundleLibRuntimeToJarRelease UP-TO-DATE
    > Task :unityLibrary:mobilenotifications.androidlib:processReleaseJavaRes NO-SOURCE
    > Task :launcher:parseReleaseLocalResources UP-TO-DATE
    > Task :unityLibrary:mobilenotifications.androidlib:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
    > Task :launcher:processReleaseManifestForPackage UP-TO-DATE
    > Task :unityLibrary:mobilenotifications.androidlib:mergeReleaseNativeLibs NO-SOURCE
    > Task :unityLibrary:mobilenotifications.androidlib:copyReleaseJniLibsProjectOnly UP-TO-DATE
    > Task :unityLibrary:mobilenotifications.androidlib:prepareReleaseArtProfile UP-TO-DATE
    > Task :launcher:processReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
    > Task :launcher:bundleReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
    > Task :launcher:extractReleaseVersionControlInfo UP-TO-DATE
    > Task :launcher:checkReleaseDuplicateClasses UP-TO-DATE
    > Task :launcher:javaPreCompileRelease UP-TO-DATE
    > Task :launcher:desugarReleaseFileDependencies UP-TO-DATE
    > Task :launcher:mergeExtDexRelease UP-TO-DATE
    > Task :launcher:mergeReleaseShaders UP-TO-DATE
    > Task :launcher:compileReleaseShaders NO-SOURCE
    > Task :launcher:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
    > Task :launcher:mergeReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
    > Task :launcher:processReleaseJavaRes NO-SOURCE
    > Task :launcher:mergeReleaseJavaResource UP-TO-DATE
    > Task :launcher:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
    > Task :launcher:writeReleaseAppMetadata UP-TO-DATE
    > Task :launcher:collectReleaseDependencies UP-TO-DATE
    > Task :launcher:configureReleaseDependencies UP-TO-DATE
    > Task :launcher:parseReleaseIntegrityConfig UP-TO-DATE
    > Task :launcher:validateSigningRelease UP-TO-DATE
    > Task :unityLibrary:configureCMakeRelWithDebInfo[arm64-v8a]
    > Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac FAILED
    99 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 97 up-to-date
    UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)




    import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
                              ^
      symbol:   class NonNull
      location: package androidx.annotation
    D:\Cod\GooglePlay\Games\WorkingMemory\WorkingMemory\Library\Bee\Android\Prj\IL2CPP\Gradle\unityLibrary\src\main\java\io\appmetrica\analytics\plugin\unity\AdRevenueSerializer.java:4: error: cannot find symbol
    import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
                              ^
      symbol:   class Nullable
      location: package androidx.annotation
    D:\Cod\GooglePlay\Games\WorkingMemory\WorkingMemory\Library\Bee\Android\Prj\IL2CPP\Gradle\unityLibrary\src\main\java\io\appmetrica\analytics\plugin\unity\AdRevenueSerializer.java:12: error: cannot find symbol
    import io.appmetrica.analytics.AdRevenue;
                                  ^
      symbol:   class AdRevenue
      location: package io.appmetrica.analytics
    D:\Cod\GooglePlay\Games\WorkingMemory\WorkingMemory\Library\Bee\Android\Prj\IL2CPP\Gradle\unityLibrary\src\main\java\io\appmetrica\analytics\plugin\unity\AdRevenueSerializer.java:13: error: cannot find symbol
    import io.appmetrica.analytics.AdType;
                                  ^
      symbol:   class AdType
      location: package io.appmetrica.analytics
    D:\Cod\GooglePlay\Games\WorkingMemory\WorkingMemory\Library\Bee\Android\Prj\IL2CPP\Gradle\unityLibrary\src\main\java\io\appmetrica\analytics\plugin\unity\AdRevenueSerializer.java:19: error: cannot find symbol
        public static AdRevenue fromJsonString(@NonNull String adRevenue) throws JSONException {
                      ^
      symbol:   class AdRevenue
      location: class AdRevenueSerializer
    D:\Cod\GooglePlay\Games\WorkingMemory\WorkingMemory\Library\Bee\Android\Prj\IL2CPP\Gradle\unityLibrary\src\main\java\io\appmetrica\analytics\plugin\unity\AdRevenueSerializer.java:55: error: cannot find symbol
        private static AdType GetAdType(@NonNull String adTypeStr) {
                       ^
      symbol:   class AdType
      location: class AdRevenueSerializer
    D:\Cod\GooglePlay\Games\WorkingMemory\WorkingMemory\Library\Bee\Android\Prj\IL2CPP\Gradle\unityLibrary\src\main\java\io\appmetrica\analytics\plugin\unity\AppMetricaConfigSerializer.java:3: error: cannot find symbol
    import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
                              ^
      symbol:   class NonNull
      location: package androidx.annotation
    D:\Cod\GooglePlay\Games\WorkingMemory\WorkingMemory\Library\Bee\Android\Prj\IL2CPP\Gradle\unityLibrary\src\main\java\io\appmetrica\analytics\plugin\unity\AppMetricaConfigSerializer.java:7: error: cannot find symbol
    import io.appmetrica.analytics.AppMetricaConfig;
                                  ^
      symbol:   class AppMetricaConfig
      location: package io.appmetrica.analytics
    D:\Cod\GooglePlay\Games\WorkingMemory\WorkingMemory\Library\Bee\Android\Prj\IL2CPP\Gradle\unityLibrary\src\main\java\io\appmetrica\analytics\plugin\unity\AppMetricaConfigSerializer.java:14: error: cannot find symbol
        public static AppMetricaConfig fromJsonString(@NonNull String config) throws JSONException {
                      ^
      symbol:   class AppMetricaConfig
      location: class AppMetricaConfigSerializer
    D:\Cod\GooglePlay\Games\WorkingMemory\WorkingMemory\Library\Bee\Android\Prj\IL2CPP\Gradle\unityLibrary\src\main\java\io\appmetrica\analytics\plugin\unity\AppMetricaProxy.java:4: error: cannot find symbol
    import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
                              ^
      symbol:   class NonNull
      location: package androidx.annotation
    D:\Cod\GooglePlay\Games\WorkingMemory\WorkingMemory\Library\Bee\Android\Prj\IL2CPP\Gradle\unityLibrary\src\main\java\io\appmetrica\analytics\plugin\unity\AppMetricaProxy.java:5: error: cannot find symbol
    import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
                              ^
      symbol:   class Nullable
      location: package androidx.annotation
    D:\Cod\GooglePlay\Games\WorkingMemory\WorkingMemory\Library\Bee\Android\Prj\IL2CPP\Gradle\unityLibrary\src\main\java\io\appmetrica\analytics\plugin\unity\AppMetricaProxy.java:12: error: cannot find symbol
    import io.appmetrica.analytics.AppMetrica;
                                  ^
      symbol:   class AppMetrica
      location: package io.appmetrica.analytics
    D:\Cod\GooglePlay\Games\WorkingMemory\WorkingMemory\Library\Bee\Android\Prj\IL2CPP\Gradle\unityLibrary\src\main\java\io\appmetrica\analytics\plugin\unity\AppMetricaProxy.java:13: error: cannot find symbol
    import io.appmetrica.analytics.AppMetricaConfig;
                                  ^
      symbol:   class AppMetricaConfig
      location: package io.appmetrica.analytics
    D:\Cod\GooglePlay\Games\WorkingMemory\WorkingMemory\Library\Bee\Android\Prj\IL2CPP\Gradle\unityLibrary\src\main\java\io\appmetrica\analytics\plugin\unity\AppMetricaProxy.java:14: error: cannot find symbol
    import io.appmetrica.analytics.ModulesFacade;
                                  ^
      symbol:   class ModulesFacade
      location: package io.appmetrica.analytics
    D:\Cod\GooglePlay\Games\WorkingMemory\WorkingMemory\Library\Bee\Android\Prj\IL2CPP\Gradle\unityLibrary\src\main\java\io\appmetrica\analytics\plugin\unity\AppMetricaProxy.java:15: error: cannot find symbol
    import io.appmetrica.analytics.StartupParamsCallback;
                                  ^
      symbol:   class StartupParamsCallback
      location: package io.appmetrica.analytics
    D:\Cod\GooglePlay\Games\WorkingMemory\WorkingMemory\Library\Bee\Android\Prj\IL2CPP\Gradle\unityLibrary\src\main\java\io\appmetrica\analytics\plugin\unity\AppMetricaProxy.java:16: error: package io.appmetrica.analytics.plugins does not exist
    import io.appmetrica.analytics.plugins.PluginErrorDetails;
                                          ^
    D:\Cod\GooglePlay\Games\WorkingMemory\WorkingMemory\Library\Bee\Android\Prj\IL2CPP\Gradle\unityLibrary\src\main\java\io\appmetrica\analytics\plugin\unity\DeferredDeeplinkListenerProxy.java:3: error: cannot find symbol
    import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
                              ^
      symbol:   class NonNull
      location: package androidx.annotation
    D:\Cod\GooglePlay\Games\WorkingMemory\WorkingMemory\Library\Bee\Android\Prj\IL2CPP\Gradle\unityLibrary\src\main\java\io\appmetrica\analytics\plugin\unity\DeferredDeeplinkListenerProxy.java:4: error: cannot find symbol
    import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
                              ^
      symbol:   class Nullable
      location: package androidx.annotation
    D:\Cod\GooglePlay\Games\WorkingMemory\WorkingMemory\Library\Bee\Android\Prj\IL2CPP\Gradle\unityLibrary\src\main\java\io\appmetrica\analytics\plugin\unity\DeferredDeeplinkListenerProxy.java:5: error: package org.jetbrains.annotations does not exist
    import org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull;
                                    ^
    D:\Cod\GooglePlay\Games\WorkingMemory\WorkingMemory\Library\Bee\Android\Prj\IL2CPP\Gradle\unityLibrary\src\main\java\io\appmetrica\analytics\plugin\unity\DeferredDeeplinkListenerProxy.java:9: error: cannot find symbol
    import io.appmetrica.analytics.DeferredDeeplinkListener;
                                  ^
      symbol:   class DeferredDeeplinkListener
      location: package io.appmetrica.analytics
    D:\Cod\GooglePlay\Games\WorkingMemory\WorkingMemory\Library\Bee\Android\Prj\IL2CPP\Gradle\unityLibrary\src\main\java\io\appmetrica\analytics\plugin\unity\DeferredDeeplinkListenerProxy.java:10: error: cannot find symbol
    import io.appmetrica.analytics.StartupParamsCallback;
                                  ^
      symbol:   class StartupParamsCallback
      location: package io.appmetrica.analytics
    D:\Cod\GooglePlay\Games\WorkingMemory\WorkingMemory\Library\Bee\Android\Prj\IL2CPP\Gradle\unityLibrary\src\main\java\io\appmetrica\analytics\plugin\unity\DeferredDeeplinkListenerProxy.java:11: error: cannot find symbol
    import io.appmetrica.analytics.StartupParamsItem;
                                  ^
      symbol:   class StartupParamsItem
      location: package io.appmetrica.analytics
    D:\Cod\GooglePlay\Games\WorkingMemory\WorkingMemory\Library\Bee\Android\Prj\IL2CPP\Gradle\unityLibrary\src\main\java\io\appmetrica\analytics\plugin\unity\DeferredDeeplinkListenerProxy.java:12: error: cannot find symbol
    import io.appmetrica.analytics.StartupParamsItemStatus;
                                  ^
      symbol:   class StartupParamsItemStatus
      location: package io.appmetrica.analytics
    D:\Cod\GooglePlay\Games\WorkingMemory\WorkingMemory\Library\Bee\Android\Prj\IL2CPP\Gradle\unityLibrary\src\main\java\io\appmetrica\analytics\plugin\unity\DeferredDeeplinkParametersListenerProxy.java:3: error: cannot find symbol
    import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
                              ^
      symbol:   class NonNull
      location: package androidx.annotation
    D:\Cod\GooglePlay\Games\WorkingMemory\WorkingMemory\Library\Bee\Android\Prj\IL2CPP\Gradle\unityLibrary\src\main\java\io\appmetrica\analytics\plugin\unity\DeferredDeeplinkParametersListenerProxy.java:4: error: cannot find symbol
    import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
                              ^
      symbol:   class Nullable
      location: package androidx.annotation
    D:\Cod\GooglePlay\Games\WorkingMemory\WorkingMemory\Library\Bee\Android\Prj\IL2CPP\Gradle\unityLibrary\src\main\java\io\appmetrica\analytics\plugin\unity\DeferredDeeplinkParametersListenerProxy.java:5: error: package org.jetbrains.annotations does not exist
    import org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull;
                                    ^
    D:\Cod\GooglePlay\Games\WorkingMemory\WorkingMemory\Library\Bee\Android\Prj\IL2CPP\Gradle\unityLibrary\src\main\java\io\appmetrica\analytics\plugin\unity\DeferredDeeplinkParametersListenerProxy.java:9: error: cannot find symbol
    import io.appmetrica.analytics.DeferredDeeplinkListener;
                                  ^
      symbol:   class DeferredDeeplinkListener
      location: package io.appmetrica.analytics
    D:\Cod\GooglePlay\Games\WorkingMemory\WorkingMemory\Library\Bee\Android\Prj\IL2CPP\Gradle\unityLibrary\src\main\java\io\appmetrica\analytics\plugin\unity\DeferredDeeplinkParametersListenerProxy.java:10: error: cannot find symbol
    import io.appmetrica.analytics.DeferredDeeplinkParametersListener;
                                  ^
      symbol:   class DeferredDeeplinkParametersListener
      location: package io.appmetrica.analytics
    D:\Cod\GooglePlay\Games\WorkingMemory\WorkingMemory\Library\Bee\Android\Prj\IL2CPP\Gradle\unityLibrary\src\main\java\io\appmetrica\analytics\plugin\unity\DeferredDeeplinkParametersListenerProxy.java:11: error: cannot find symbol
    import io.appmetrica.analytics.StartupParamsCallback;
                                  ^
      symbol:   class StartupParamsCallback
      location: package io.appmetrica.analytics
    D:\Cod\GooglePlay\Games\WorkingMemory\WorkingMemory\Library\Bee\Android\Prj\IL2CPP\Gradle\unityLibrary\src\main\java\io\appmetrica\analytics\plugin\unity\DeferredDeeplinkParametersListenerProxy.java:12: error: cannot find symbol
    import io.appmetrica.analytics.StartupParamsItem;
                                  ^
      symbol:   class StartupParamsItem
      location: package io.appmetrica.analytics
    D:\Cod\GooglePlay\Games\WorkingMemory\WorkingMemory\Library\Bee\Android\Prj\IL2CPP\Gradle\unityLibrary\src\main\java\io\appmetrica\analytics\plugin\unity\DeferredDeeplinkParametersListenerProxy.java:13: error: cannot find symbol
    import io.appmetrica.analytics.StartupParamsItemStatus;
                                  ^
      symbol:   class StartupParamsItemStatus
      location: package io.appmetrica.analytics
    D:\Cod\GooglePlay\Games\WorkingMemory\WorkingMemory\Library\Bee\Android\Prj\IL2CPP\Gradle\unityLibrary\src\main\java\io\appmetrica\analytics\plugin\unity\StartupParamsCallbackProxy.java:3: error: cannot find symbol
    import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
                              ^
      symbol:   class NonNull
      location: package androidx.annotation
    D:\Cod\GooglePlay\Games\WorkingMemory\WorkingMemory\Library\Bee\Android\Prj\IL2CPP\Gradle\unityLibrary\src\main\java\io\appmetrica\analytics\plugin\unity\StartupParamsCallbackProxy.java:4: error: cannot find symbol
    import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
                              ^
      symbol:   class Nullable
      location: package androidx.annotation
    D:\Cod\GooglePlay\Games\WorkingMemory\WorkingMemory\Library\Bee\Android\Prj\IL2CPP\Gradle\unityLibrary\src\main\java\io\appmetrica\analytics\plugin\unity\StartupParamsCallbackProxy.java:8: error: cannot find symbol
    import io.appmetrica.analytics.StartupParamsCallback;
                                  ^
      symbol:   class StartupParamsCallback
      location: package io.appmetrica.analytics
    D:\Cod\GooglePlay\Games\WorkingMemory\WorkingMemory\Library\Bee\Android\Prj\IL2CPP\Gradle\unityLibrary\src\main\java\io\appmetrica\analytics\plugin\unity\StartupParamsCallbackProxy.java:9: error: cannot find symbol
    import io.appmetrica.analytics.StartupParamsItem;
                                  ^
      symbol:   class StartupParamsItem
      location: package io.appmetrica.analytics
    D:\Cod\GooglePlay\Games\WorkingMemory\WorkingMemory\Library\Bee\Android\Prj\IL2CPP\Gradle\unityLibrary\src\main\java\io\appmetrica\analytics\plugin\unity\StartupParamsCallbackProxy.java:10: error: cannot find symbol
    import io.appmetrica.analytics.StartupParamsItemStatus;
                                  ^
      symbol:   class StartupParamsItemStatus
      location: package io.appmetrica.analytics
    D:\Cod\GooglePlay\Games\WorkingMemory\WorkingMemory\Library\Bee\Android\Prj\IL2CPP\Gradle\unityLibrary\src\main\java\io\appmetrica\analytics\plugin\unity\AppMetricaPushHelper.java:3: error: cannot find symbol
    import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
                              ^
      symbol:   class NonNull
      location: package androidx.annotation
    D:\Cod\GooglePlay\Games\WorkingMemory\WorkingMemory\Library\Bee\Android\Prj\IL2CPP\Gradle\unityLibrary\src\main\java\io\appmetrica\analytics\plugin\unity\AppMetricaPushHelper.java:5: error: cannot find symbol
    import io.appmetrica.analytics.AppMetricaConfig;
                                  ^
      symbol:   class AppMetricaConfig
      location: package io.appmetrica.analytics
    D:\Cod\GooglePlay\Games\WorkingMemory\WorkingMemory\Library\Bee\Android\Prj\IL2CPP\Gradle\unityLibrary\src\main\java\io\appmetrica\analytics\plugin\unity\AppMetricaPushHelper.java:12: error: cannot find symbol
        public static AppMetricaConfig getAppMetricaConfigFromUnityJsonString(@NonNull String jsonString) throws JSONException {
                      ^
      symbol:   class AppMetricaConfig
      location: class AppMetricaPushHelper
    D:\Cod\GooglePlay\Games\WorkingMemory\WorkingMemory\Library\Bee\Android\Prj\IL2CPP\Gradle\unityLibrary\src\main\java\io\appmetrica\analytics\plugin\unity\DeferredDeeplinkListenerProxy.java:19: error: cannot find symbol
        class Delegate implements DeferredDeeplinkListener {
                                  ^
      symbol:   class DeferredDeeplinkListener
      location: interface DeferredDeeplinkListenerProxy
    D:\Cod\GooglePlay\Games\WorkingMemory\WorkingMemory\Library\Bee\Android\Prj\IL2CPP\Gradle\unityLibrary\src\main\java\io\appmetrica\analytics\plugin\unity\DeferredDeeplinkParametersListenerProxy.java:20: error: cannot find symbol
        class Delegate implements DeferredDeeplinkParametersListener {
                                  ^
      symbol:   class DeferredDeeplinkParametersListener
      location: interface DeferredDeeplinkParametersListenerProxy
    D:\Cod\GooglePlay\Games\WorkingMemory\WorkingMemory\Library\Bee\Android\Prj\IL2CPP\Gradle\unityLibrary\src\main\java\io\appmetrica\analytics\plugin\unity\ECommerceAmountSerializer.java:3: error: cannot find symbol
    import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
                              ^
      symbol:   class NonNull
      location: package androidx.annotation
    D:\Cod\GooglePlay\Games\WorkingMemory\WorkingMemory\Library\Bee\Android\Prj\IL2CPP\Gradle\unityLibrary\src\main\java\io\appmetrica\analytics\plugin\unity\ECommerceAmountSerializer.java:7: error: package io.appmetrica.analytics.ecommerce does not exist
    import io.appmetrica.analytics.ecommerce.ECommerceAmount;
                                            ^
    D:\Cod\GooglePlay\Games\WorkingMemory\WorkingMemory\Library\Bee\Android\Prj\IL2CPP\Gradle\unityLibrary\src\main\java\io\appmetrica\analytics\plugin\unity\ECommerceAmountSerializer.java:13: error: cannot find symbol
        public static ECommerceAmount fromJsonString(@NonNull String ecommerce) throws JSONException {
                      ^
      symbol:   class ECommerceAmount
      location: class ECommerceAmount<message truncated>

 3. 

    Build completed with a result of 'Failed' in 205 seconds (205391 ms)
    3 errors
    UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)

What have I tried:

Android reslover + settings of reslover

Change by unity compile and target sdk (by the way, this is another separate problem)

Check/uncheck unty "custom gradle files"

Chanje jeri to android studio in external propertys (Although I may well have messed up during this)

Build last buildet version in git


As a last resort, just drop links to gradle tutorials for android- windows&unity
Other:
Thanks a lot in advance for any help, especially if these are the answers to the subqueries in order

Yeah, I don't know what to do. Who to ask for help, even for a fee, although I still have no money. That's what to do damn it
